# Yii Custom Widget

Tags: php, javascript, widget, yii, google-visualization

I am trying to create a Yii widget that will generate Google Charts (http://code.google.com/apis/chart).

How do I make a widget that writes code in both the html headers (where the javascript includes and stuff will be), and in the html body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile()
```

and

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript()
```